# React all the cards in the List are re-rendering when one card's state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**The Problem**: Whenever the user clicks the like on the card, the entire list re-renders, causing all the cards to re-render.

Here's a GIF: [image: Error]

I have a state called `list` which is an array of card objects in the parent component, `Category`. Each card has the following structure:

```
{
  id: some-id,
  title: 'Some Title',
  likes: 1,
  category: 'design'
}
```

Then I have a `<ul>` in my JSX and I am mapping over the state that has the list, as the following:

```
const cards = this.state.list.map(card => (
  <Card 
    key={card.id} 
    title={card.title}
    likes={card.likes}
  />
));
```

In the `Card` component, when the user triggers the event listener by clicking the like button, what's happening is that instead of just updating the state for that card, it's updating the entire list, causing all the cards to re-render.

**EDIT:** I'm actually not passing `updateLike`. The structure is a little bit messy, but let me explain:

I created a remote NodeJS server that has the object with the `likes` counter. The parent component, `Category` and its state `list` array does not have access to it. However, the individual card component does.

The **Card** Component has 3 states: `likeBtnClass`, `icon`, and `text`.

To update the like counter for the card, I'm doing the following:

```
onLikeClick() {
  // Props
  const { category, id } = this.props;
  // Update the icon
  const state = this.state;
  const updatedIcon = (state.icon === 'like') 
    ? 'like_outline'
    : 'like';
  const updatedClass = (state.icon === 'like') 
    ? 'btn'
    : 'btn btn-saved';

  let urlString = `${API_ENDPOINT}/${category.toLowerCase()}/${id}`;

  // If current state = saved: post req to like
  let reqURL = (updatedIcon === 'like') ? `${urlString}/like` : `${urlString}/unlike`;

  this.setState({
    btnClass: updatedClass,
    icon: updatedIcon,
  });

  // Send POST request via axios
  axios.post(reqURL, {});
}
```

Comment: are you using event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropogation()?

Comment: Does `card.id` value changes when `updateLike` is called?

Comment: @prakashsharma no, the `card.id` stays the same; only the like counter is updated.

Comment: @NikhilGoswami I tried that, but that's not the issue. I know that the `event` object is passed via `onClick` handler, but I'm not using that anywhere.

Comment: we should see the `updateCardLikeCounter` code or maybe event the parent component to see how you are changing the state

Comment: you should show the relevant code like `updateCardLikeCounter` and the `componentWillReceiveProps` of `card`.

Comment: Post the code, where you are updating like event (what exactly you are doing in method)

Comment: try adding a key to each card.

Comment: my guess is that you are passing a new `function` instance to each card, like `onClick={() => {this.handleClick(someParam)}}` but we need to see some code

Comment: @Panther I added it. Please check it out

Comment: @Deshak9 I added the method.

Comment: @NikhilGoswami I tried that, but that's not the issue. I know that the event object is passed via onClick handler, but I'm not using that anywhere. – narulakeshav How do you invoke onLikeClick?

Comment: Can you post your Card component?

Comment: Hi @narulakeshav , did you find the solution to rerender only single card after updation ?.

Answer (score 0):

You could set on card’s shouldComponentUpdate() that the component will be rendered only if there is a change.

Comment: can you please elaborate? What exactly is that and what goes inside that?

Comment: It’s a lifecycle method. The function gets the nextProps. So you could do it this way: shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){return !nextProps.equals(this.props)} so only if the value is true it will rerender the component

Comment: if react decides to update the **real** DOM on each `render` call that means something has change. it won't really help the OP.